# Printing a character that has been made active in text and/or math mode?

Tags: math-mode, catcodes

I am not very familiar with TeX's category codes. If I use

```
\catcode`\|=13 \renewcommand{|}{hello world}
```

then every use of `|` in my document will be replaced by `hello world`. However, how would I be able to still print the `|` sign? Of course, the circular reference

```
\catcode`\|=13 \renewcommand{|}{hello|world}
```

does not work (exceeding TeX's majestic capacity), although I would like all instances of `|` to print as `hello|world`. And, if I'm correct, the above would just hold for regular text mode. How would the above code change if `|` was to be used in math mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are usually two approaches taken to solve this problem.

### A

Save the character with original catcode in a macro before its catcode is changed. This works because catcodes are assigned at input time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mypipe}{|}
\catcode`\|=\active
\renewcommand{|}{hello\mypipe world}

\begin{document}

|

\end{document}
```

### B

Force the catcode of `|` to 12 with `\string`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`\|=\active
\renewcommand{|}{hello\string|world}

\begin{document}

|

\end{document}
```

### Math mode

A character can also be only active in math mode, that is, its mathcode can be `"8000`. To get the original meaning in this case, one can define a control sequence to be a synonym for the previous mathcode of the character:

```
\mathchardef\mymathpipe=\mathcode`\|
```

Look at the implementation of the [`icomma`](http://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package for an example.